# Segmentation fault for simple program with while loop but no error when expanded . How?

Tags: c, string, pointers, gcc

I came across this problem while teaching C Pointers to my kid brother. The purpose of the code is to read a simple string using gets() or scanf() and gives the first 4 characters of the given string as output.

Two versions of the code are given :

Code 1:

```
    char *p;

    char *cptr;
    gets(p);
    cptr = p;
    printf("%c",*(cptr));
    printf("%c",*(++cptr));
    printf("%c",*(++cptr));
    printf("%c",*(++cptr));
```

Code 2:

```
    char *p;
    int l=0;
    char *cptr;
    gets(p);
    cptr = p;
    printf("%c",*(cptr));
    while(l!=3)
    {
        printf("%c",*(++cptr));
        l++;
    }
```

If I give any input , Code 1 gives the correct answer but Code 2 gives segmentation fault . I am not able to find what the problem . I tried inputs with length more than 4 , just to be sure. The Inputs were all single words and thus no white-space is involved.

Compiler Used : GCC 4.4 ( ubuntu 14.04 64bit OS )

Isnt both the above Codes same ? If so why it gives seg.fault in code 2 ? Please help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   char *p;
   int l=0;
   char *cptr;
   gets(p);
```

`p` pointer is not initialized in both your programs, you are passing a random value to `gets`: it invokes undefined behavior. It may work in some cases and crash in others.

Of course `gets` is deprecated in C and its use should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You are using uninitialized `p` so the code invokes UB.

Use something like `char *p = malloc(1000);`